# Convert datetime to UTC using timezone sometimes works incorrectly

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a method to convert `DateTime` from local to UTC using specific time zone:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneId);
DateTime dateTimeInUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDateTime, timeZone);
return dateTimeInUtc;
```

But sometimes (I have no idea when and why, but most of the time it works correctly) this conversion works not as I expect.

For example:

- Time Zone is `-5`

[image]

- Local time is `08/28/2013 12:00:00 AM` (`DateTimeKind` is `Unspecified`)

[image]

So what do you expect after this line of code with values above?

```
DateTime dateTimeInUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(localDateTime, timeZone);
```

I expect to have a UTC time as `08/28/2013 5:00:00 AM`. But

[image]

`08/28/2013 4:00:00 AM`. It doesn't correct if timezone is -5.

Absolutely the same code worked correctly for a few month. Even when I've looked at debugger conversion was correct.


I faced the same problem with this code about 2 weeks ago (wrong conversion). But on the next day the problem disappeared without any code changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-5 is the base UTC offset, but during Daylight Savings Time that changes by 1 hour to -4.

**Daylight Saving Time (United States) 2013 began at 2:00 AM on**

Sunday, March 10

**and ends at 2:00 AM on**

Sunday, November 3

During this time most states move their clocks forward 1 hour (except for example Arizona)

Comment: But at this period I had +5 hours when I convert to UTC. 1 week ago it was 5 hours with the same code.

Comment: @SergeyGavruk What date were you using? The same? or did you happen to use a date before March 10 or after Nov. 3?

Comment: hm. Maybe the reason was really because my dates were not in this range. Thanks

Comment: @SergeyGavruk Also always make sure to use the built in functions to convert between UTC and Local. Congress has changed the dates for DST before and it varies by year. Any math you do on dates (like subtraction) should be done in UTC time when trying to calculate hour differences. There's also an ambiguous time on Nov 3, 2:00-3:00 where if I don't tell you DST or not you cannot tell which it is.. because you see 2:00 twice.

Comment: I've checked this method with different dates (using DST range) and you are right. `BaseUtcOffset` confused me. Thank you.